Getting a rank 1 jacobian for an invertible transformation?
I have $Y = g(X) = \frac{X}{\sqrt{\|X\|^2 + c}}$, where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and where $c$ is a constant. I want to obtain an expression for the pdf of $Y$, for which I need $f=g^{-1}$, such that $f(Y)=X$, to then use the Gaussian pdf.
To get $f$ we just note that $X$ and $g(X)$ are vectors in the same direction but with different lengths. Thus, to transform $Y$ into $X$ we solve for $\|X\|$ from $g(X)$, which results in $\|X\| = \sqrt{c \cdot \frac{\|Y\|^2}{1 - \|Y\|^2}}$. Thus, we have that $X=f(Y)=\frac{Y}{\|Y\|}\sqrt{c \cdot \frac{\|Y\|^2}{1 - \|Y\|^2}} = Y\sqrt{\frac{c}{1-\|Y\|^2}}$.
To my understanding, the pdf of $Y$ is given by $p_Y(Y) = p_X(X) \cdot \lvert J(f(Y)) \rvert$, where $p_Y(Y)$ is the pdf of $Y$, $p_X(X)$ is the pdf of $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, and $\lvert J(f(Y)) \rvert$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the transformation $f(Y)$.
Now, when I solve for the matrix $J(f(Y))$ I'm getting a rank 1 matrix, which is thus singular. I don't think this is right, because $f$ is invertible (except at 0), so I'm probably making some mistake somewhere. Writing $h(Y)=(1-\|Y\|^2)^{-1/2}$ My derivation of $J(f(Y))$ is as follows.
$$\frac{\partial f(Y)_j}{\partial Y_i} =
\sqrt{c} Y_j\frac{\partial h(Y)}{\partial Y_i} = 
\sqrt{c} Y_j (-2Y_i)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)(1-\|Y\|^2)^{-3/2} =
\sqrt{c} Y_j Y_i (1 - \|Y\|^2)^{-3/2}
$$
This tells me that the Jacobian matrix is given by
$$J(f(Y)) = YY^T \sqrt{c} (1 - \|Y\|^2)^{-3/2}$$
This is a rank 1 matrix as far as I can tell, because it's just proportional to $YY^T$.
Where's the problem in the derivation? Or am I missing something such that the matrix is not rank 1?

You didn't apply the product rule correctly. We should have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \sqrt{c}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}(1-\|y\|^2)^{-1/2} + y \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left[(1-\|y\|^2)^{-1/2}\right]\right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{1-\|y\|^2}}I + \sqrt{c}y\left(\frac{y^T}{(1-\|y\|^2)^{3/2}}\right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{1-\|y\|^2}}\left(I + \frac{yy^T}{1-\|y\|^2}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which has full rank. You only computed the second term in my product rule expansion.

Is it possible you derived the incorrect formula? I think the one to derive is $Y \sqrt{c/(1-|Y|^2)}$. But I still get how I applied the product rule wrong


derive = differentiate


@dherrera I think whpowell96 is correct. Your differentiation is almost correct. You forgot to account for the case $j = i$. In that case, the term involving $Y_j$ won't come out of the differentiation and give you the part corresponding to the identity matrix in the above answer.

His comments refer to a previous version of this answer where I differentiated $g$ instead of $f$. I agree with your comment though. In OP's notation, there should be an additional term with $\frac{\partial Y_i}{\partial Y_i} = I$ multiplied by a scalar function

Yes, got it. And thanks for fixing to differentiating f
